# Regex pattern to match multiple characters and split

Tags: python, regex

I haven't used regex much and was having issues trying to split out 3 specific pieces of info in a long list of text I need to parse.

```
note = "**Jane Greiz** `#1`: Should be open here .\n**Thomas Fitzpatrick** `#90`: Anim: Can we start the movement.\n**Anthony Smith** `#91`: Her left shoulder.\nhttps://google.com"
```

1. pattern1 = Parse the **Name Text**
2. pattern2 = Parse the number `#x`
3. pattern3 = Grab everything else until the next pattern 1

What I have doesn't seem to work well.  There are empty elements?  They are not grouped together?  And I can't figure out how to grab the last pattern text without it affecting the first 2 patterns.  I'd also like it if all 3 matches were in a tuple together rather than separated.   Here's what I have so far:

```
all = r"\*\*(.+?)\*\*|\`#(.+?)\`:"
l = re.findall(all, note)
```

Output:

```
[('Jane Greiz', ''), ('', '1'), ('Thomas Fitzpatrick', ''), ('', '90'), ('Anthony Smith', ''), ('', '91')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use alternatives. Put the name and number patterns after each other in a single alternative, and add another group for the match up to the next `**`.

```
note = "**Jane Greiz** `#1`: Should be open here .\n**Thomas Fitzpatrick** `#90`: Anim: Can we start the movement.\n**Anthony Smith** `#91`: Her left shoulder.\nhttps://google.com"
all = r"\*\*(.+?)\*\*.*?\`#(.+?)\`:(.*)"
print(re.findall(all, note))
```

Output is:

```
[('Jane Greiz', '1', ' Should be open here .'), ('Thomas Fitzpatrick', '90', ' Anim: Can we start the movement.'), ('Anthony Smith', '91', ' Her left shoulder.')]
```

Comment: Ah, I sort of see.  However, it still seems to chop off the last newline and throw away the URL that should still be part of the 3rd pattern.  I'm confused why, if the last pattern should be grabbing everything after?

Comment: `.*` only matches up to a newline. That's why each individual match stops at the newline.

Comment: How can I indicate to grab everything?  It should just stop when it encounters the first pattern yet again or nothing at all (the end) of the text.

Comment: That's hard. You need to specify something that it should stop at, otherwise the first match will extend to the end of the string.

Comment: It will be easier if you first split the string into each group, then use a regexp on each group to extract the parts.

Comment: But that is sort of the reason why I used regex.  There really isn't an easy way to split the string first.  And it would not be a good idea to split by just a simple "**" characters.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't the ultimate answer for everything. http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247

Comment: The regular expression needs a pattern that it can match to end each group. It's not magic, it can't figure it out by itself.

Comment: I don't disagree with you, but then how would you propose splitting this string by \*\*NAME\*\*.  If that is the way to go, I just don't know how you can with a regular .split().

Comment: `re.split(r'\n(?=\*\*)', note)` will split it at every newline that's followed by `**`. The `**` will be kept in the results because it's a lookahead.

Comment: Thanks I think that is doable and a good first step to figure out the rest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249497/discussion-between-zak44-and-barmar).